# Расположить элемент по центру по горизонтали из спойлера

Tags: html, css, center

Использую спойлер, не получается сделать чтобы выскакиваемые элементы были не под вызывающим его блоком, а в центре по горизонтали, подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить

Вот пример
http://test.asvpages.ru/tt/service1.html

код спойлера

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.spoiler_links').each(function() {

   $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //отменяем стандартное действие ссылки
      $('.spoiler_body').not($(this).next()).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

      $(this).next('.spoiler_body').fadeToggle(500);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ссылка не работает(

Comment: Сейчас бы арендовать бесплатный хостниг для примеров, а codepen для чего придумали